# Tcl/Tk: Frames misbehave when resizing.

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am relatively new to Tcl/Tk but have been working with it fairly successfully, non-stop for the last several weeks. For the most part it seems fairly straightforward. However, I've hit a snag recently which is probably simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have reduced my fairly complicated code to a few lines which demonstrate the problem.

My simple example produces two labelframes with a simple label widget in each. When I resize (i.e., expand) the main window, I want the “left” frame to resize in the y-direction only and I want the “middle” frame to resize in x and y. Those parts work fine.

However, I also want the frames to stay “stuck” to each other when resized. That is, I want the “middle” frame to stay stuck up against the “left” frame when  they both resize. Instead, I see a gap expanding between the two.

Again, this is a simplified bit of code from a more complicated program. I am trying to avoid mixing grid and pack commands in the same program and, in the original more complicated program, using grid became very unwieldy. So a solution using “pack” would be preferred. But proper explanation would be a good start.

My small example:

```
 #!/usr/bin/wish

 ## Set up two main frames
 set frameLeft [labelframe .frameLeft]
 set frameMiddle [labelframe .frameMiddle]

 pack $frameLeft -fill y -expand 1
 pack $frameMiddle  -fill both -expand 1 
 pack $frameLeft $frameMiddle -side left -anchor nw

 ## Instead of the previous 3 lines, I also tried:
 #pack $frameLeft -fill y -expand 1 -side left -anchor nw
 #pack $frameMiddle  -fill both -expand 1 -side left -anchor nw

 ## Set up component in LEFT frame
 set frameOne [labelframe $frameLeft.frameOne]
 set labelOne [label $frameOne.labelOne -text "Label One:"]

 pack $labelOne -anchor nw
 pack $frameOne -anchor nw

 ## Set up component in MIDDLE frame
 set frameTwo [labelframe $frameMiddle.frameTwo]
 set labelTwo [label $frameTwo.labelTwo -text "Label Two:"]

 pack $labelTwo -side left
 pack $frameTwo -anchor nw
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it usually helps when debugging a complex layout to put garish colors on the frames. Sure, you won't leave them in production, but it does make understanding the behavior of the geometry manager you're using much simpler.

When I try your code, I see that the two widgets are both being allocated the same amount of space in the horizontal direction; the `.frameLeft` widget is then sticking to the left side of that space whereas the `.frameMiddle` widget is filling out the space it has been allotted. So the problem isn't the behavior of the widgets *within* their “space packet”, but rather the allocation of space.

Now, with `pack`, the allocation of the extra space is controlled by the `-expand` option; the extra room is shared between the packets that have expansion enabled for them. This means that to get the layout you want, you should simply *not* set `-expand 1` for `.frameLeft`.

Comment: There's also the algorithm for handling things when there's _not enough_ room, but that always confuses me. I prefer to use `grid`, which is more complicated but easier to use to do complex layouts. (Also, why are you using `labelframe` widgets without `-text` labels?)

Comment: Thanks! I see where I went wrong. 

Again, my example is a simplification of a complicated problem, so my actual problem isn't quite what it seemed to be but with your explanation, I was able to figure it out. 

As I say, I am still somewhat new to this and obviously I haven't reached quite the comfort level I thought I had.

Comment: @user1074069 I can only advise experimenting, remembering that some problems really are better solved with `grid` (there are some cunning tricks) and trying to keep your real UI simple enough for your users.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you prefer a "pack" answer, but grid is usually much easier to deal with since the "sticky" option handles the filling and expansion in an easier to handle semantic. I'm a little surprised that you had trouble with it. Unfortunately, I'm locked into "grid"-think. So does the following "grid" solution do what you are looking for?

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

## Set up two main frames
set frameLeft [labelframe .frameLeft]
set frameMiddle [labelframe .frameMiddle]

grid $frameLeft -row 0 -column 0 -sticky nse
grid $frameMiddle -row 0 -column 1 -sticky nsew
grid columnconfigure . {0 1} -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

## Set up component in LEFT frame
set frameOne [labelframe $frameLeft.frameOne]
set labelOne [label $frameOne.labelOne -text "Label One:"]

grid $frameOne -sticky nw
grid $labelOne -sticky nw

## Set up component in MIDDLE frame
set frameTwo [labelframe $frameMiddle.frameTwo]
set labelTwo [label $frameTwo.labelTwo -text "Label Two:"]

grid $frameTwo -sticky nw
grid $labelTwo -sticky nw
```

Comment: I expected “grid” to be more appropriate but it started to give me more trouble as I was building up a complicated layout from separate components. Perhaps my inexperience is still showing. Now that I have what I want, I will refactor with grid and see what I have learned. Thanks.